# How do I use PHP, Twitter API to get more or all of my followers?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have a twitter api php script successfully spits out the last 100 of my followers

```
$flwrs_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/exampleuser.json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $flwrs_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlout = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($curlout, true);

foreach($response as $friends){
    $id = $friends['id'];   
$screen_name = $friends['screen_name'];
....
```

(I used exampleuser instead of my own account)
How do I extend this to include more or all of my followers?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Twitter API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids) for `GET followers/ids` the request should return up to 5000 followers.

However, if not all followers are returned by the API, there should be a `next_cursor` element in the response which can be used to retrieve the next batch of followers. You only have to append the value of `next_cursor` as `cursor` to the request (see also the API documentation).

Please note that you are using Version 1 of the Twitter API which has been deprecated recently. That is, it will stop working probably early next year. You should upgrade to [Version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) as soon as possible. There are new guidelines in place, one of them is that all requests must be authenticated with oAuth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Florian. BTW stumbing around I think I found the correct way to do what I was looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Florian. BTW stumbing around I think I found the correct way to do what I was looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong.

after using the:

```
 $code=$tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1/followers/ids'),
            array('screen_name' => $user, 'cursor' => $cursor));
```

technique to grab all 5000 followers (user ids). I use the following code to grab batches of 100 (user details) at a time:

```
$status_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=";
$lastNum=$last; // $lastNum=100;
$i=$first;     // $i=0;
while($i<$lastNum){
    if ($i==($lastNum-1)){
        $status_url = $status_url . "$followers[$i]";
    }else{  
        $status_url = $status_url . "$followers[$i],";
    }

    $i++;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $status_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlout = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($curlout, true);

$i = 0;
foreach($response as $friends){
    $id = $friends['id'];
    $screen_name = $friends['screen_name'];
    $name = $friends['name'];
    $thumb = $friends['profile_image_url'];
    $url = $friends['screen_name'];
    $location = $friends['location'];
    $description = $friends['description'];
    echo "$i) $id $screen_name $name $location $description<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

I realize I need to put "sleep" in between each of these "batches of 100", but I'm not quite sure how much to use.

Comment: First of all you should definitely use Version 1.1 of the Twitter API, since 1.0 will be deprecated very soon. The Twitter developer site says that you get 180 API calls every 15 minutes (in Version 1.0 it was 350 calls per hour). If I understand it correctly you should be able to look up 180000 users per 15 minutes which should be enough. Since you can make 180 requests in 15 minutes I would sleep for 5 seconds between requests.

Comment: Btw, with Version 1.1 of the API you have to do the lookup requests also with oAuth, i.e. you should send them with `$tmhOauth`.